What was the religious or cultural significance of the Kid's village that made it a target for the antagonists?
In the 2024 film Monkey Man, one of the central plot points revolves around the village where the Kid (played by Dev Patel) and his mother Neela lived. Their village was targeted by the corrupt police chief Rana, who was acting on the orders of Baba Shakti, a prominent Hindu nationalist religious figure associated with the Sovereign Party. This attack ultimately led to Neela's tragic death.
As the film reveals, Baba Shakti is essentially the mouthpiece and campaigner for the Sovereign Party, which seems to be promoting an agenda of discrimination against minority groups, particularly Muslims. This is evidenced by the protest signs denouncing discrimination against Indian Muslims shown interspersed with the scene where the Kid was training with Alpha and the Hijras (themselves minorities who were also victims of Baba's thugs).

Now, here's where I'm a bit confused—was the Kid's village singled out and attacked because it was comprised of minorities? Based on the Kid and his mother appearing to be devotees of the Hindu god Hanuman, I'd assume they aren't Muslims. But then, the Sovereign Party and Baba Shakti are portrayed as Hindu nationalist types, so it doesn't quite add up why they'd attack a Hindu village.
What minority group did the Kid's village belong to that made them a target for Baba and Rana? Or if they weren't part of a minority group, what was the reason they were targeted?
I'm admittedly not super familiar with the nuances of Indian politics, religious dynamics, and minority demographics, so I'm hoping those more familiar with the cultural context could shed some light on this plot point.
What was the religious or cultural significance of the Kid's village that made it a target for the antagonists?
